# How can I code a Javascript Alert to only populate once per web session?

Tags: javascript, alert

I am creating a website for my final and have coded an "adult content" alert on my homepage. I am trying to get the site to populate that message only once per session but right now it populates every time you go to the homepage.

The class is HTML and CSS but we were asked to include one basic javascript code and the "alert" seemed most appropriate. I have tried googling this question different ways to get help but it's mostly providing information that is above a very very basic level of javascript.

This is my current code:

```
<script>
alert("WARNING! Adult Language and Content! The following is intended for 
immature adults only. Viewer Discretion is Advised.")
</script>
```

This is the site:
http://mysite.du.edu/~mdarienz/index.html

Since this is for a final, I don't need the code to fix it but if you could maybe steer me in the right direction for how to approach it I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Try [Session cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Session_cookies).

Comment: Try local storage or cookie to identify your site and throw alert based on it.

Answer (score 3):

sessionStorage is all you need. Just add this in your script.

```
<script>
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('showAlert') != "false"){
        alert("WARNING! Adult Language and Content! The following is intended for 
immature adults only. Viewer Discretion is Advised.");
        sessionStorage.setItem('showAlert', "false");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data on session basis using the `sessionStorage` api provided by most of the browsers. So you can store a bool(or a number or a string) in the `sessionStorage` to check if you have shown the alert or not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// check if api exists
if (sessionStorage !== undefined) {
    // check if you have any item with the key 'showAlert'
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("showAlert") == null) {
        alert("Show alert");
        // Set the item with the key 'showAlert' so that 
        // this won't be executed later.
        sessionStorage.setItem("showAlert", false);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage, the stored data is saved across browser sessions.And, data stored in localStorage has no expiration time (not like sessionStorage)

Please change your code to this

```
<script>
    var seenIt = localStorage.getItem('seenIt')
    if(string.isNullOrEmpty(seenIt)){
        alert("WARNING! Adult Language and Content! The following is intended for immature adults only.Viewer Discretion is Advised.");
        localStorage.setItem('seenIt', "yes");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sessionStore we can make sure that per tab/session alert is shown rather than showing each time we load the page.

```
!sessionStorage.getItem('alert') && 
(!alert('WARNING! Adult Language and Content! The following is intended for immature adults only. Viewer Discretion is Advised.') && 
sessionStorage.setItem('alert', true));
```